# Scale series of number up by uniform amount

Tags: calculus

I have a series of numbers associated with a grid that determine the hue of each cell. Some of these cells are too dark and I'd like to scale them up slightly yet not to exceed the max value of $1$.

The decimal value that determines brightness for each cell is in a range from $0$ to $1$. I would like to uniformly increase these values. Is there a way to increase values that are close to 0 by a significant amount, but as values approach $1$ they increase a very slight amount, not to exceed $1$?

For example. A starting value of $.1$ might increase to $.3$ but a starting value of $.9$ might only increase to $.93$.

I'm really not sure how to approach this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways.  Really you want to take $x$ to $f(x)$, where both $x, f(x)$ are within $[0,1]$  You presumably want $f(x)$ to be monotonic so brighter cells stay brighter, and you want $f(x) \ge x$ so you are brightening.  One simple choice is $f(x)=x^\alpha$, where $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$